# Selecting a X number of lines using Regular Expressions within the given separators

Tags: php, regex

So, im trying to select **only** the content **inside** the `---` traces, which is obviously **multiline**, but I have to use regular expressions due the fact not all entries will contain this very same amount of meta data.

The example im trying to match using **PHP**'s `preg_match` function is this:

```
---
Title: A fresh start to all of us. Right?
Slug: a-fresh-start-to-all-of-us-right
Author: admin
Date: 12/05/2015 16:29
Draft: false
Image: http://placehold.it/400x280
Tags: codesans, install, markdown
---

# A fresh start comes, after all.
```

As you can see, nothing below the `---` traces can be matched.

Im trying to match with this regular expression: 
`/^(.*)?[^\n]$/gm`
but it doesn't seems to work so far. I already tried to tokenize the traces to make them delimiters-like but it also didn't work (this regex: `/^(\-{3})?(.*)?(\-{3})?[^\n]$/gm`).

Any guidance, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DOTALL` flag i.e. `s` for this:

```
/(\A|\R)-{3}\R(.+?)-{3}(\R|\z)/s
```

btw there is no `g` flag in `PHP`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH3mV7/5)

Comment: @sln yeah... im trying to fix it using the regular expression anubhava provided, but no progress still. :/

Comment: @anubhava Yes, these traces are the content delimeters. This section will be placed at the top of the file. I tried using your regex but this time it didn't matched a single line... I think im gonna have to use a workaround...

Comment: Did you see updated working demo. If that's not working for you then provide a sample data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have. Sorry for not providing you the sample I was using. Im trying with two (it may be more, im not the one who is going to write everything) additional and optional traces. As seen on [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH3mV7/3).

Comment: Now it isn't, btw let OP write the requirements

Answer (score 1):

Could use something like this `(?m)^---.*\s+([\S\s]*?)^---`
This way uses the normal dot.

```
 (?m)
 ^ --- .* \s+ 
 ( [\S\s]*? )                   # (1)
 ^ ---
```